# Scrape P tag inside class in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract text inside "P" tag from the class inside class but it is not working

```
 <div class="sques_quiz">
 <div class="wp_quiz_question testclass"><span class="quesno">2. </span></p>
 <p>What is capital of India?</p>
 </div>
 <div type="A" class="wp_quiz_question_options">[A] Delhi />[B] Kolkata<br 
/>[C] Mumbai<br />[D] None of the above
            </div>
 <p><a class="wp_basic_quiz_showans_btn" 
 onclick="if(jQuery(this).hasClass('showanswer')){ jQuery(this).html('Show 
 Answer').removeClass('showanswer'); jQuery('.ques_answer_3652').slideUp(); 
  }else { jQuery(this).html('Hide Answer').addClass('showanswer'); 
  jQuery('.ques_answer_3652').slideDown();}">Show Answer</a></p>
 <div class="wp_basic_quiz_answer ques_answer_3652" style="display:none;">
 <div class="ques_answer"><b>Correct Answer:</b> A [Delhi ]</div>
 <div class="answer_hint"><b>Answer Explanation:</b></p>
  <p>   Delhi is the capital city of india</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

So far my code is

```
    for foo in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'sques_quiz'}):
        bar = foo.find("div", attrs={'class': 'wp_quiz_question testclass'})
        for a in bar.find('p'):
            print(a)
```

Giving error for a in bar.find('p'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I want output as

What is the capital of India?

[A] Delhi

[B] Kolkata

[C] Mumbai

[D] None of the above

Correct Answer: A [Delhi ]

Answer Explanation:   Delhi is the capital city of India

Comment: Find only looks for the first occurrence. Maybe you should use find_all if you want to iterate over it. If it is the first one the one you need, you can use find and then you do not need to iterate.

Comment: Thanks let me check it.

Comment: Hi friend, I have updated my post please have a look.

Comment: That is one messy HTML. Is there one question per page or do you have to iterate through series of questions?

Comment: There are 10 questions in a page but for a single question that's the code, I found.

Comment: Do not know if jQuery is playing some role here or not.

Comment: Can you give a link?

Comment: https://www.gktoday.in/gk-current-affairs-quiz-october-4-2017/

Comment: Updated my answer. Give me a feedback if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an elegant solution but it gets the job done i think.

```
from bs4 import *
import requests

site = 'https://www.gktoday.in/gk-current-affairs-quiz-october-4-2017/'
request = requests.get(site).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(request,'html.parser')

answer_row = 0
for foo in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'sques_quiz'}):
    #print(foo)
    print(foo.find_next('p').text)
    question = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'wp_quiz_question_options'})[answer_row].text
    answer = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'ques_answer'})[answer_row].text
    answer_hint = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'answer_hint'})[answer_row]
    answer_hint = answer_hint.text + answer_hint.find_next('p').text
    print(question)
    print(answer)
    print(answer_hint)
    print('')
    answer_row += 1
```

And this is the output.

```
Who of the following have won the Nobel Prize in Chemistry 2017?
[A] Jean-Pierre Sauvage, Fraser Stoddart and Ben Feringa[B] Tomas Lindahl and Paul L. Modrich[C] Brian K. Kobilka and Robert J. Lefkowitz[D] Jacques Dubochet, Joachim Frank and Richard Henderson

Correct Answer: D [Jacques Dubochet, Joachim Frank and Richard Henderson]
Answer Explanation:The Nobel Prize in Chemistry 2017 was awarded to Jacques Dubochet, Joachim Frank and Richard Henderson for developing cryo-electron microscopy for the high-resolution structure determination of biomolecules in solution. It’s a method of simplifying and improving the imaging of biomolecules.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it was my mistakes. I have updated question

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about the find_next method. I will study your code deeply and if confusion arises, will ask you. I am now learning it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you need to use `find_all` to iterate over it because `find` only returns the first element it finds.

This code gives the result exactly in the format you wanted:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.gktoday.in/gk-current-affairs-quiz-october-4-
2017/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'sques_quiz'})[:1]:
    ques = div.find('div', {'class':'wp_quiz_question 
    testclass'}).find('p').text.strip()
    options = div.find('div', 
    {'class':'wp_quiz_question_options'}).text.split('[')
    ans = div.find('div', {'class':'ques_answer'}).text.strip()
    exp = div.find('div', {'class':'answer_hint'}).text.strip()
    print(ques)
    print('['+options[1])
    print('['+options[2])
    print('['+options[3])
    print('['+options[4])
    print(ans)
    print(exp)
```

And this is the result:

```
Who of the following have won the Nobel Prize in Chemistry 2017?
[A] Jean-Pierre Sauvage, Fraser Stoddart and Ben Feringa 
[B] Tomas Lindahl and Paul L. Modrich
[C] Brian K. Kobilka and Robert J. Lefkowitz
[D] Jacques Dubochet, Joachim Frank and Richard Henderson

Correct Answer: D [Jacques Dubochet, Joachim Frank and Richard 
Henderson]
Answer Explanation:
The Nobel Prize in Chemistry 2017 was awarded to Jacques Dubochet, 
Joachim Frank and Richard Henderson for developing cryo-electron  
microscopy for the high-resolution structure determination of 
biomolecules in solution. It’s a method of simplifying and improving the 
imaging of biomolecules.
```

To print all the results on the page, change this line: `for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'sques_quiz'})[:1]:` to this: `for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'sques_quiz'}):`